# File.delete() isn't deleting the .Json file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to delete a json file I just created, The file is in the same directory as the workplace so I didn't include it when creating the new File object.
I also closed the output stream before trying to delete the file by using .close() method.

```java
import java.io.File;
public static void processFilesForValidation(String name, Scanner obj, PrintWriter logFile) {
        int count = 0;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
            String[] line = obj.nextLine().split(",", -1);
            if (count == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        if (line[i].equals(" ")) {
                            throw new CSVFileInvalidException();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                outputStream = new PrintWriter((new FileOutputStream(name + ".json", true)));
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                System.out.println("Could not create json file " + name
                                        + ". Program will terminate after deleting any corrupted files and closing any opened files.");
                                obj.close();
                                outputStream.close();
                                String fname = name + ".json";
                                File file = new File(fname);
                                file.delete();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (CSVFileInvalidException eCsvFileInvalidException) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "File " + name + ".CSV is invlaid: field is missing. \nFile is not converted to JSON.");
                        int detected = line.length - 1;
                        logFile.println("\nFile " + name + ".CSV is invalid. \nMissing field:" + detected
                                + " detected, 1 missing");
                        for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                            if (line[j].equals(" ")) {
                                logFile.print(line[j] + "***, ");
                            } else {
                                logFile.print(line[j] + ", ");
                            }
                        }

                        logFile.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        String fname= name+".JSON";
                        File file = new File(fname);
                        file.delete();
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }
        

    }
```

The code is a little long but this is the method, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your code doesn't check the return from `File.delete()` so it does not know whether it worked.  However, that won't tell you why it didn't work.  You might try to use `Files.delete()` instead, since on failure it will throw an exception giving more information.

Comment: It's saying that I didn't close the output stream even though I did which is confusing me even more.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a new outputStream every time around the loop.  As far as I can tell, you only close it on a couple of errors. So, on loop #2, the first outputStream is left dangling and not closed.